# Using a for and if statement

Tags: java

Please, when I try to run my main class, I get an error telling me that I am missing a return statement for the following code, however i have used a return statement. I am new to Java so kindly explain.

```
public boolean addPassenger(Person a){
       for(int i =0; i < passengers.length; i++){
         if(passengers[i]==null){
           passengers[i]=a;
           NumOfPassengers++;
           return true;
         }
         else
           return false;
       }

     }
```

Comment: Why use a loop for this? Just do `if (passengers.length > 0 && passengers[0] == null) {... return true;} else {return false;}`

Comment: If it's empty, I wanna insert the input a into that slot in the array @fabian

Comment: This is not what your code would be doing, however, since in the first iteration there's a `return` statement which prevents any other iterations from running.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `return` statement for every possible valid path through the code.  In your case, you are missing a return statement for the case where `passengers.length == 0`.